# Characterize a function that preserves a partition

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

This is (part of) an old exam question in an introduction to set theory course:

> Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a function with $A_\alpha \subseteq X$ for each $\alpha \in \Lambda$.

...

> 1.4. If $\alpha \in \Lambda$, when is  $f(X-A_\alpha)=Y-f(A_\alpha)$? Prove your answer.

So as I understand I need to characterize the function $f$ with the given properties, or give the prerequisite conditions that will ensure that it has the given property. What I could come up with is:

1. $f$ must be onto $Y$.
2. $f(X-A_\alpha) \cap f(A_\alpha)=\emptyset$ - so $f$ preserves the domain structure in this sense.
3. $f$ does not need to be one-to-one.

Is there something else I am missing? I am not sure whether the question is just referring to any specific set in the indexed system of sets, or whether it implicates that for all $\alpha$ the condition should hold...if the latter is the case then maybe more can be said, even though $\Lambda$ is possibly just a singleton?

Comment: Is $(A_\alpha)_{\alpha \in \Lambda}$ a partition of $X$? The title suggests it, but it is not mentioned in your text.

Comment: I am just referring to $\{(X-A_\alpha),A_\alpha\}$ being a partition for some fixed $\alpha$...from my understanding the $A_\alpha$'s could definitely overlap and there is no reason to believe that $\cup_{\alpha \in \Lambda} A_\alpha$ will cover $Y$?

Comment: And where is $\Lambda$ definied? Or: why do you write "with $A_\alpha \subseteq X$ for each $\alpha \in \Lambda$" and not simply "with $A \subseteq X$"?

Comment: It is not explicitly defined, but within the context $\Lambda$ is just a collection of indices...that is the only information given in the question, so it is somewhat ambiguous I guess?

Comment: Some possible readings, differences highlighted in **bold**. Version 1: "Let $f: X\to Y$ and $\Lambda$ some set of indices and $A_\alpha \subseteq X$ for each $\alpha \in \Lambda$. For **a fixed** $\alpha \in \Lambda$, when is $f(X - A_\alpha) = Y - f(A_\alpha)$?". Version 2: "Let $f: X\to Y$ and $\Lambda$ some set of indices and $A_\alpha \subseteq X$ for each $\alpha \in \Lambda$. When is $f(X - A_\alpha) = Y - f(A_\alpha)$ **for any** $\alpha \in \Lambda$?". (Maybe Version 3: "Let $f: X\to Y$. When is $f(X - A_\alpha) = Y - f(A_\alpha)$ **for any $\Lambda$ and any $\alpha \in \Lambda$**?")

Answer (score 1):

Let me rephrase your question more formally, because I think that is what you are asking:

For $f: X\to Y$ and $Z\subseteq X$ prove that
$$
f(X-Z) = Y - f(Z)
$$
is equivalent to
$$
f(X) = Y \quad \wedge \quad f(X -Z) \cap f(Z) = \emptyset.
$$

(I.e. for a concrete $Z := A_\alpha$ your conditions 1 and 2 are necessary and sufficient.)

Proof for "$\Rightarrow$":
$$
f(X) = f(X - Z) \cup f(Z) = (Y - f(Z)) \cup f(Z)
\overset{f(Z) \subseteq Y}{=} Y
\\
f(X - Z) \cap f(Z) = (Y - f(Z)) \cap f(Z) = \emptyset
$$

Proof for "$\Leftarrow$":
$$
Y - f(Z) = f(X) - f(Z)
= (f(X - Z) \cup f(Z)) - f(Z)
\overset{(*)}{=} f(X - Z)
$$
Note that $(*)$ works because $(A \cup B) - B = A$ for disjoint $A,B$, which is given by the second condition.

In other words, $f(X) = Y$ says $f$ is surjective. And $f(X - Z) \cap f(Z) = \emptyset$ says that $f(z) \in f(Z) \leftrightarrow z \in Z$.

Comment: Hi Thorsten...thanks so much for your effort...sorry maybe I was not very clear. If you look at my question, the part in blockquote (gray shading) is the question that was asked in the exam. My answer to the question at this stage basically constitutes what you have proved above - so in other words - I already have that. My question is, can anything more be said? Am I perhaps missing some crucial condition on $f$?

Comment: No, you are definitely not missing some condition of $f$, because my proof is not only in one direction but in *both* directions.

Comment: To answer the question "when is ...?":  "It is $f(X -Z) = Y -f(Z) $ exactly when f fulfills the conditions 1 and 2." (No other condition needed).